# Automate fly login if the team is backed by UAAC

Tags: cloudfoundry-uaa, concourse

How does one automate the fly login if the team is backed by uaa? Currently the fly cli kicks out a login link that you have to manually open in a separate browser window. Something more elegant for that would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

In order to automate a `fly login` for a team that uses uaa or github, you need to automate clicking on the link that fly gives you, signing into the backend service on some sort of browser, and then waiting for fly to tell you to close the browser window.

Any web driver client can accomplish this task in a few lines of code, and the concourse team uses [agouti](https://github.com/sclevine/agouti/) + [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) when we're using go for testing.

```
session, _ := Fly("login", "-c", atcUrl, "-n", teamName, "--ca-cert", certPath)
Eventually(session).Should(gbytes.Say("or enter token manually:"))

output := string(session.Out.Contents())
re := regexp.MustCompile("https://.*")
submatches := re.FindStringSubmatch(output)
loginUrl := submatches[0]

Expect(page.Navigate(loginUrl)).To(Succeed())
```

After this, you may need to automate logging on to your account in the browser. Whichever driver you chose should make this easy.

For instance, our code for this part looks like:

```
Expect(page.FindByName("username").Fill(cfConfig.AdminUser)).To(Succeed())
Expect(page.FindByName("password").Fill(cfConfig.AdminPassword)).To(Succeed())

Expect(page.FindByButton("Sign in").Click()).To(Succeed())
```

Any three-legged auth flow will use the browser, because the third party services we use to authenticate users require that a browser login occurs.